# Disable Xorg session in sddm

Tags: xorg, kde, wayland, nixos, sddm

I have an issue with Xorg where if I disconnect my external display (AMD/Nvidia laptop), sddm logs me out completely so I lose all my work. I've hence switched to Wayland with which the problem doesn't occur. Obviously that's an issue for another question.

However, I also have an issue where SDDM intermittently forgets my default login session and reverts to Xorg. So I'll start using the machine, let it go to sleep or unplug the monitor and I'll lose all my work.

So working around both these problems, how can I disable the Xorg session or force Wayland?

Obviously I still need Xorg for X-Wayland so a solution without entirely removing Xorg would be desirable.